# OpenGL: GL_LINE_SMOOTH not supported on all cards; wont even draw the lines, unless

Tags: c++, opengl, lines

First of all, whats the purpose of this code?

```
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
```

I could put there `GL_DONT_CARE` but it doesnt make my lines drawn, **unless** i use `glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)`

So im asking if theres some built in mechanism to make it draw the lines even if the smooth lines arent supported (So it would draw them without antialising...)

Or do i have to make own functions for it and checking if smooth lines are supported etc... and every time i want to draw smooth lines, i need to call this function that checks whether or not its supported? argh.

**Edit:** The lines are smooth on my other card, on my other card they dont even show up, unless i disable smooth lines. So that is the problem, not glEnable(GL_BLEND)

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the driver to me.

Comment: @ypnos - if he didn't enable blending, then it's not

Comment: blending is enabled, look my edits now

Comment: @Newbie: does the other card support blending?

Answer (score 6):

`glHint` as the name implies is a **hint** to the driver. It does not necessary achieve anything. The actual functioning of `glHint` depends on the graphics driver.

Also, to enable `LINE_SMOOTH`ing, you need to have blending enabled. Did you enable `GL_BLEND` ? And while you're at it, choose your glBlend func too!

Example:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: i edited my first post now, the lines are rendered fine on other card, but with the card that doesnt support smooth lines, it wont render them at all, unless i disable gl_line_smooth

Comment: @Newbie: What's the other card?